# How to do a PCA with 0 (zero) values

Tags: r, pca

I want to do a PCA in R with monthly rainfall values. Since there is no rain during winter, quite a few values in my columns are 0.

When I run the PCA, the following message appears in the console: Error in cov.wt(z) : 'x' must contain finite values only

I think what R is telling me here is that it does not like my 0 values.

So, I tried to change my 0 values to 'real numbers' by multiplying everything with 1.0000000001. But even if I do that and run R again with the new values, it pops up with the same message.

I read that I would need to either get rid of the rows with any missing values in them (which I can't) or use a PCA code that can deal with missing values by somehow imputing them. But my 0's are actual values, not missing values.

I find a lot of information on the web on how to deal with missing values or NA values but nothing on how to deal with zero values. Does anyone have any suggestions how I can do this? Many thanks for your help!

Comment: If you use `prcomp` with defaults, your variables are centered anyway. Also, `1.0000000001 * 0 == 0`. However, I don't see a programming question here. It's probably more of a statistics question.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that "Error in cov.wt(z) : 'x' must contain finite values only" is complaining that some covariances are non-finite, i.e. NA/NaN. This can happen if you have variables that have a standard deviation of 0.

Example code:

```
latent = rnorm(10)
data = data.frame(rep(0,10), #10 0's
                  latent+rnorm(10),  #latent and noise
                  latent+rnorm(10),     #
                  latent+1.5*rnorm(10)) #
colnames(data) = c("zeros","var1","var2","var3")

library(psych)
principal(data)     #error!
principal(data[-1]) #no errors
```